# C#: How can I open and close an Excel workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, aspose

**Does anyone know how to simply open and close an Excel workbook?**

I don't need to read any data from the file, I just need to open and close it. (*)

I'm guessing that I'll need to reference the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly.

---

*Reason: I've already configured pivot table information with a 3rd party library (Aspose). Now I need to read the generated pivot table.

Unfortunately, the Aspose library can't generate the pivot table at runtime. It needs someone to [open the file with Excel](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/80143/80041/showthread.aspx#80041) so that Excel can generate the pivot table values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

after referencing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel also Make sure to clean up in the finally.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

        Excel.ApplicationClass _Excel;
        Excel.Workbook WB;
        Excel.Worksheet WS;

    try
        {

        _Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open("FILENAME",
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            //do something

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WB);

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_Excel);


        }
```

Comment: While implementing this i encountered error There is no constructor defined for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass type please refer to this for corrections. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016264/microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-has-no-constructor-defined

Comment: I would also add `_Excel.Quit()` to finally block to close excel app.

Comment: Well the VB Project of the workbook remains open even after closing the workbook, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google gives me this on code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Consider using System.Diagnostics.Process to start, monitor, and close Excel. This site gives a good intro: http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/Process.aspx, including running with an invisible window and sending input to it.