# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass has no constructor defined

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I tried to follow [How to open an Excel file in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm)  tutorial, i.e. added a reference on the `Com` tab to `Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library` and tried to compile code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//...
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();//error here
//...
```

and faced a compile-time error, saying

> There is no constructor defined for
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass type.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
Excel._Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

Comment: Well, Office 14 + VS 2010 worked with .NET 3.5 and ApplicationClass. Now with VS 2012, Office 14 only is recognized using .NET 4 and I get the same error that you was having.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following to open it:

```
xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application");
```

CreateObject creates and returns a reference to a COM object. Documentation may be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Just added a reference to the documentation. I haven't tried a method similar to the one you tried, so not sure if it works or not, but I just checked a recent VB.NET project I wrote that works and that's how I went about it.

Comment: +1: Vlad Spreys gave the answer I needed. Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: No problem, actually just voted his answer up as well, it's probably a cleaner way to go about it even though this method works as well.

Comment: Probably I'll check your sugesstion sometime too:)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C# 4.0 (.NET 4)
you can go with much easier syntax

```
var app = new Application( );

var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("test.xls");
```

In regards to **var**: it makes you job easier cuz C# decides which type to chose and go for.
If interested you can read about **dynamic** and **var** *styles*.

Remember that interop prior to C# 4.0 is totally a different phenomenon and how C# used to handle Microsoft objects.

just so you know how different, this is how you should've coded it before C# 4.0 to talk to a **Word** document.

```
object fileName = @"WordFile.docx";
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object readOnly = true;
var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: well described why to use **Application()** instead of **ApplicationClass()** here at

[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2004/02/05/67872.aspx)