# How do you automatically close a specific excel file when it is already open (without killing excel)?

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to close an excel file when it is already open? I have written a code that can determine if a specific excel file is already open, however I cannot close the file once it has been determined to be open. I have tried the following method (see below) to close a workbook and excel application:

`// The name of my workbook is "workbook", while the Excel application is named "excel."

workbook.Close(true);
excel.Quit();`

Performing the latter code does not close the already open Excel window. It may also be of assistance to know the code I am using to determine if a file is open (it is provided below):

```
// The following checks to see if a file is open and returns truth1 as  "true" if the file is open and "false" if the file is closed. 
file = new FileInfo(file_name);
truth1 = IsFileinUse(file);
// ...
protected static bool IsFileinUse(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
           if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Again, I cannot create a program in which I "kill Excel". I just need know how to close an already open Excel window if its path is the same as the one I am trying to read and write to.

Comment: Do you already tried this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971269/closing-an-open-excel-workbook-in-c-sharp

Comment: The .close() command does not close the already open file; which is what is what is mainly focused on in all the solution I find on this subject (including the one you just recommended).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing an Excel Workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440138/closing-an-excel-workbook)

Comment: It is not the same, as I cannot "kill Excel," which is what the leading solution to your link recommends. Also using .close() or .quit() does not remove the already open Excel file from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on below sample code :-

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application exl = new Excel.Application();

# open a file
Excel.Workbook wbook = exl.Workbooks.Open("some_file.xlsx");

# To close the file
wbook.Close();

exl.Quit();
```

**Edit 1:-**

You can refer below link if above solution not works for you :-

[Closing an Excel Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440138/closing-an-excel-workbook)

Comment: The .Close() and .Quit() command **are not closing the already open Excel file.** I want to close the already open file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows API, to close a certain Window by it's title.

This will invoke a Window-Close, so it will prompt the user if he really wants to close:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
```

And then

```
IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "MyFile.xlsx - Excel");
if (windowPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Document not open");
     return;
}

SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

If you need to force a close, even if the file has been modified, you only can kill the related excel-process. But keep in mind that this will forcefully kill other excel-windows as well, if they are running within the same excel-process-instance.

```
  using System.Diagnostics;
  ...
  Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

  foreach (Process p in processes)
  {
      if (p.MainWindowTitle == "MyFile.xlsx - Excel")
      {
          p.Kill();
          break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is there  way to close an Excel window without prompting the user, and without killing Excel. Thank you for your assistance.