# Open password-protected Excel Workbook with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I recently started new project at work where I would like to work a bit with JavaScript. It's my first contact with JS and I am already struggling with one reference.

I am trying to open an workbook (Excel) using JS, but it's secured by password. I don't know what is proper syntax to pass optional objects such as `"Password:=***"`. Here is what I have:

```
function test() {
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var Location = "W:/MyFolder/MyFile.xlsm"
    Excel.Visible = true;
    var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location:="****");
}
```

It works fine, it opens the file as intended however I can't add password variable - for example:

```
var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location, Password:="****");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named parameters in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/named-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there seems not to be a method to omit optional arguments with `JScript` and `ActiveX`-functions. Simply omit them like in :

```
var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location, , , , "password");
```

is a syntactical error in `JScript`.

Using `undefined` seems to lead to `0` in `ActiveX`-functions. So

```
var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location, undefined, undefined, undefined, "password");
```

will not work because the fourth argument `Format` cannot be `0`. It must be `1` to `6` according to [Workbooks.Open Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)

So the only way seems to be **not** to omit but to hand over possible values for them:

```
var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location, 0, false, 1, "password");
```

will work.

---

Edit:

In this special case, since all optional arguments are `System.Object`s, to hand over `null` for optional arguments works for me:

```
var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location, null, null, null, "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [the Workbook.Open MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx). Basically, the password is expected as the 5th argument.

```
var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Location, missing, missing, missing, "****");
```

You can specify the 2nd-4th arguments as missing/null. Not sure how to do this in javascript; in PowerShell it's `$missing = [System.Reflection.Missing]::Value` and in c# it's [`Type.Missing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526685/c-how-can-i-open-and-close-an-excel-workbook)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am familliar with msdn .open, the problem is in JS syntax - I cannot apply it in JS :) The "missing" parameter makes sense, although it doesnt work (neither "null")....